# Fail to create virtual environment (have Anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda

As the title suggests, when I try to create virtual environment in cmd with

```
py -m venv resume_1
```

The following error occurred.

```
Error: Command '['D:\\Python\\Project\\resume_1\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
```

Other posts suggest reinstalling python and choosing 'all users' option. However, my python is installed along with Anaconda, so should I reinstall Anaconda? Are there even any options for me to choose 'all users' under Anaconda at all? I tried to modify the python under Anaconda to 'all users' but the same error occurred.
I also tried to create a virtual environment with a newly installed python (the newest version), but the same error also appeared.

Edit1: after using the code to try to create the virtual environment in anaconda

```
conda create -n resume_1 python=3.8 anaconda
```

I run into this error

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scikit-learn-1.0.1-py38hf11a4ad_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::scikit-learn-1.0.1-py38hf11a4ad_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\Brian Tse\.conda\envs\resume_1\Scripts\.scikit-learn-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: failed to create process.

return code: 1

()
```

And the cmd still shows,

```
(base) PS D:\Python\Project>
```

Comment: probably depends on what the command `py` is creating. since you want to use conda, the command appears to be `conda create -n resume_1 python=x.x anaconda`, of course  replace x.x with the python version you want to use.

Comment: may I ask what does this code does exactly?

Comment: it sets up the virtual environment, equivalent to your `py` command but includes conda dependencies. what does `conda -V` return?

Comment: After I put in the code, there is this error ```ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scikit-learn-1.0.1-py38hf11a4ad_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::scikit-learn-1.0.1-py38hf11a4ad_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\Brian Tse\.conda\envs\resume_1\Scripts\.scikit-learn-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr: failed to create process.

return code: 1

()```  and the cmd still show ```(base) PS D:\Python\Project>```

Comment: the command i quoted is mentioned as a possible solution https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10165#issuecomment-858831217

Comment: why are you using `py -m venv`? it should  create an empty environment, anaconda dependencies won't be available after you activate it

Comment: If I just want to create a simple virtual env for my Django project, and don't need any functions of anaconda in the foreseeable future. How do I do so? It seems like I can't just create ```py-m venv file_name``` in my current situation. Not sure if improper deletion caused it, I say this because python I discovered that I retained file 'Python39-32', but the 'IDLE' is missing, which may happen when you delete it wrongly???

Comment: never mind, I tried reinstalll python with 'all user' and now it works.